# Firebase Firestore security rules - read all nested docs based on resource (but it's null)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure which part... Thanks for all the clarification I can get.

So I have a collection named Bases that looks like this:

```
{
  "id1": {
    "name": "My base 1",
    "roles": {
      "idUser_123": {
        "name": "John"
      }
    }
  },
  "id2": {
    "name": "My base 2",
    "roles": {
      "idUser_456": {
        "name": "Jane"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

idUser_123 log in and want to access his collection. So I do:
`db.collection('bases').get()`

And I use a match rule to make sure John is not reading Jane's bases. And that's where I think I'm wrong cause I'm using rule for filter purpose.

```
match /bases/{document=**}{
    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.roles;
}
```

Which failed because resource is null... I tried to do this:

```
match /bases/{baseId}{
    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.roles;
}
```

This work in the simulator when requesting specific document but fails when I'm get() without baseId from client - cause I want them all.

So how am I supposed to handle this very basic use case (IMO)?

I can't put all user's baseId in user.token as it'll be over 1000 bytes quite fast.

I can make an other collection Roles to create a relation between a baseId and my user but that's seems overengineered for a simple use case.

Or I can make the request on a server and filter `where("roles", "has", user.uid)` ? Defeat the purpose of fetching data on client side very very quickly in my opinion...

Any recommendation on how to address this will be gladly appreciated! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, your query is demanding to receive all of the documents in bases, but your rules do not allow anyone to simply receive all documents.  It's important to realize that [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  They do not strip documnts from a query - this actually does not scale.  If a rule puts requirements on who can query certain documents based on their contents, the query will have to use a filter that matches what the rule requires.

Secondly, your data isn't structured in a way that the client can perform a filter of only certain documents based on the user's UID.  Firestore doesn't have queries that can check for the existence of a map field.  It can only check for map values.  You might want to restructure your document data so that the client can actually perform a query with a filter to get only the documents for the current user.

If roles was an array of UIDs:

```
  "id1": {
    "name": "My base 1",
    "roles": [ "idUser_123" ]
  },
```

Then the client could filter on that field:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection("bases")
    .where("roles", "array-contains", uid)
```

And you could enforce the use of that filter in rules:

```
match /bases/{document=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.roles;
}
```

But you might want to do something different.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought in a way. So if I don't want someone to access protected documents, I must query and apply filters on server-side... Which is ok, I'd have the exact same problem with any other DB. I just thought Firestore could do some magic here :) Thanks for your answer and precisions on filters !

Comment: On a sidenote, the last rule you put in your answer will not work as it'll say resource is null. I've tried this way even if not recommended...

Comment: `resource` should not be null for read operations.  If you have a specific problem with a rule, I suggest asking a new question with the full code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Ok it was null because I was using /document=** in my path in the simulator. Rookie mistake... Thanks again for the help.