# Firebase Firestore: Nested Security rules for global read access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is a follow up on this post: [Firebase Firestore security rules - read all nested docs based on resource (but it's null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107041/firebase-firestore-security-rules-read-all-nested-docs-based-on-resource-but/65112388#65112388)

I'm having a hard time figuring how Firestore works!

So let's say I have this Bases collections:

```
{
  name: "Base 1",
  roles : {
     user_1: true
  }
},
{
  name: "Base 2",
  roles : {
     user_2: true
  }
}
```

I want to fetch all Base where user_1 is in resource.roles. I do :
`db.collection('bases').where('roles.user_1', '==', true).get()`

And it works great. All server side so no one can try to alter the filter: All good.

But, I want to enforce this filter with a security rule in firestore. Just to be sure! So I've wrote:

```
function hasRole(){
    return request.auth.uid in resource.data.roles
}
match /bases/{document=**}{
    allow read: if true; // signedIn() && hasRole();
}

match /bases/{baseId}{
    // allow read: if signedIn() && hasRole();
    allow update, delete: if false && signedIn()
    allow create: if signedIn()
}
```

And it works when I try to access a specific resource in the rule simulator but now my `.get()` method receive a not-enough permission. Funny enough, When I uncomment the read into `/bases/{baseId}` it works perfectly (if I comment the `/bases/{document=**}` of course).

So I can make it work but I'd still like to understand why the {document=**} rule work in simulator and not when I'm trying to fetch from a server.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

P.S: I didn't find a way to simulate a nodejs .get() in the simulator which is not super convenient to learn this stuff. Any resource on that will be read and helpful.

Comment: Have you declared Service and Database Declaration as mentioned in the [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#service_and_database_declaration)? Also please have look into the next [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) regarding Recursive Wildcards.

Comment: @NibrassH Yes, all the rules in my post are encapsuled into `match /databases/{database}/documents { .... }`. I wonder if I should put LIST instead of READ inside /bases/document=** but didn't get the time to try that yet...

Comment: Is the code running the query using the firestore libraries or the Admin SDK? How is SignedIn() defined? Also, could you clarify which rules are actually being used, it's slightly confusing to guess between the rules comments and the explanation.

Comment: It is very confusing! But you guessed right, I had it mixed up between client and server side and it was indeed my rule's function signedIn() that was not authenticated. Not sure how I authenticate a client user on server side though but I managed to make it work on client site. My first confusion was really to understand that /bases/{baseId} will also apply when fetching a list with multiple documents...

Comment: If you discovered what the issue was and a fix for it please add it as an answer so that other users could benefit from the information.